# Express a Proposition In Formal Logic

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am doing a question where I have to express: **There is no largest prime number,**
in formal logic.
This is the solution given:

Of course this is a true statement, so it could be expressed by the logically
equivalent formula “1 = 1,” but even if we didn’t know this, we could transcribe the
statement directly as:
$¬(∃p.   IS­PRIME(p) ∧ (∀q. IS­PRIME(q) \implies p ≥ q))$

My first question is in what way does 1 = 1 mean there is no largest prime number?

Secondly, to me the transcribed statement says that **for all prime numbers q, there exists a prime number p that is greater than or equal to it** (shouldn't it be just greater than?), and then there is the not at the start of the statement, I'm not sure why that is there or if it even makes sense to have it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formalization of the statement :

> There is no largest prime number

is correct; it can be translated also as :

> > $\forall p[Prime(p) \rightarrow \exists q (Prime(q) \land (p < q))]$

that means :

> for every prime number $n$, there is a prime number $q$ such that $p < q$.

The two formulae are equivalent; starting from the formula :

> > $¬∃p[IS­PRIME(p)∧∀q(IS­PRIME(q) \rightarrow p≥q)]$

we can rewrite is, using first the rules for quantifiers [$\lnot \exists$ is equivalent to $\forall \lnot$] and De Morgan, as :

> $∀p[¬ IS­PRIME(p) \lor \lnot ∀q(IS­PRIME(q) \rightarrow p≥q)]$

then, using again the rules for the quantifiers and the equivalence between $\lnot p \lor q$ and $p \rightarrow q$, as :

> $∀p[IS­PRIME(p) \rightarrow ∃q \lnot (IS­PRIME(q) \rightarrow p≥q)]$

and finally, using the equivalence between $\lnot (p \rightarrow q)$ and $p \land \lnot q$, as :

> $∀p[IS­PRIME(p) \rightarrow ∃q (IS­PRIME(q) \land \lnot (p≥q))]$.

Comment: why did you convert the 'implies' into 'and'?

Comment: I guess this means that it should be grater than and equal to rather than just greater than?

Comment: @HaniSayegh - I've omitted the last simple step : $\lnot ( p \ge q)$ is equivalent to $p <q$ ("not greater-or-equal" means "less than").

Answer (score 2):

One way to express There is no largest prime number in formal logic:
$$\forall p \exists q [\operatorname{prime}(q) \land (p<q)] $$

Comment: It translates into "For every number p, there exists a prime number q such that p < q". 

1) Am I correct translating from formal logic into human language? 
2) I struggle to understand how this proves that there is no largest prime number? Because p is not prime.

Answer (score 1):

The translation mentioned in the post is correct. Your suggested sentence that says there is no prime $p$ such that for all primes $q$ we have $p\gt q$ is trivially true, for given a $p$, take $q=p$. We need to know nothing about primes to assert the truth of that sentence. It is true even if $ISPRIME(k)$ is interpreted as being true only $k=2$, $8$, and $15$.

As to the "not" at the beginning, note that $\lnot(\exists \varphi(p))$ is logically equivalent to $\forall p(\lnot \varphi(p)$. The first was chosen presumably because of its somewhat greater faithfulness to the ordinary mathematical English we started with. I would myself prefer to use a universal quantifier, as suggested by Mauro Allegranza. But, to repeat, the translation of the post is correct, and we cannot replace $\ge$ by $\gt$ keeping the rest unchanged.

Comment: But if we pass the not through the statement we have:  '∀p ¬Prime(p) or ∃q  ¬Prime(q)  ⟹   p < q' right? This sounds like there is a q that is not prime such that p < q for all non prime p's which doesn't sound correct?

Comment: I would suggest being **very** careful with implication. When you are negating $A\implies B$, that is, $\lnot A\lor B$, we get $A\land \lnot B$.